# QSslKey and "Private Key Invalid"

Tags: macos, qt, openssl, x509

I am using OpenSSL 1.0.2k on OS X and integrated in to my project. I have generated the key and SSL certificate programmatically:

```cpp
QSslCertificate localCertificate = QSslCertificate(QByteArray(buffer, size));
// ...
QSslKey privateKey(QByteArray::fromRawData(keybuffer, size), QSsl::Rsa);
```

`privateKey` is coming as INVALID on MacOS/iOS. keybuffer has the appropriate key data. I'm able to print, check the size etc. Only `QSsslKey` is coming as invalid.

I able to store the `keyByffer` and certificate in file. Both are valid. However I'm not able to build `QSslKey` from `keyBuffer`.

I transferred the key and certificate files to Windows, and the same Key and certificate work perfectly.

Any idea why I'm not able to build QSslKey on MacOS/iOS

Initially I thought it is problem with openSSL library on MacOS. However If I use openssl(0.9.8) command line on MacOS to generate the certificate and key, it works perfectly.

Comment: When programmatically creating a key and certificate, the key pair must be created first. The X.509 certificate binds an identity to a public key, so the key pair must exist first. Its not clear to me how the certificate is created first, before the key pair exists. I think you need to show more of your code. My guess is your code is not doing what the OpenSSL commands do.

Comment: @jww, would you like to help on this related post of mine (similar Mac OSX problem): [How to perform successful SSL encryption with pkcs12/pfx in Qt on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45865375/514235)