# How to perform successful SSL encryption with pkcs12/pfx in Qt on Mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, openssl, pkcs#12

Novice to Qt and developing a cross platform app, which requires SSL authentication from the server as well as client sides The .pem based encryption is working on Linux, Android, Windows. However there are problems with Mac OSX. Our code looks like below:

```
QFile privateKeyFile(":/Certificate.pem");  // --> has certificate + key
privateKeyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);      
setLocalCertificateChain(QSslCertificate::fromPath(":/Certificate.pem", QSsl::Pem));
setPrivateKey(QSslKey(privateKeyFile.readAll(), QSsl::Rsa));
```

In above code `privateKey().isNull()` returns `true` for Mac. When we referred [this post](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/283), it says that Mac doesn't support .pem based encryption.

> The Secure Transport back-end to curl only supports client IDs that are in PKCS#12 (P12) format; it does not support client IDs in PEM format because Apple does not allow us to create a security identity from an identity file in PEM format without using a private API. And we can't use the private API, because apps that use private API are not allowed in any of Apple's app stores.

With my limited understanding, I interpreted that .pem is not a good idea for SSL communication with the server. Please stop me if it's wrong!

Hence, we decided to move to .pfx for all the platforms. We already had a .pfx file with a passphrase. We converted above code to be compatible with .pfx (i.e. "Certificate.pfx", we had this old file along with "Certificate.pem"). Instead of `QSsl::Pem`, we tried `QSsl::Der`. But as expected, it didn't work. However, there was no encryption error either, but we are sure that we are doing something wrong. :-)

We referred this post and try to regenerate a .pfx from .pem, but that also didn't help.
[QSslCertificate::importPkcs12 fails to parse PFX file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39394029)
In above case, the `QSslCertificate::importPkcs12()` returns false for the original .pfx file. Even if we generate a new .pfx from the command line, that also fails for the above function.

***Question*: Can someone help with exact way of performing the .pfx encryption with the server?

.pem authentication is also fine.**

**Note**:

- Server supports both .pfx & .pem. That we confirmed with regular C OpenSSL libraries. But we want to achieve it using Qt.
- We are open to formats other than .pfx, should they work in all the platforms

Comment: Very confusing. Are you doing ssl client authentication? That's somewhat rare if you are. If your not, then you don't have a private key so you don't need Pkcs#12.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I have limited knowledge in SSL. In nutshell, we have a old code which uses C functions to authenticate with server. It uses a .pfx certificate which is converted to .pem and then exchanged with the server. Now we have to port that code to Qt. Using .pem, it works as already demonstrated in above code. However, it doesn't work in Mac alone. While searching in internet, we got a github post, which suggests that Mac doesn't support .pem, which is also mentioned in the Qn. So we thought of resorting back to .pfx. Now we don't know how to do that. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Have you tried separating the certificate and the client key files, convert them to DER format and load them one by one?

Comment: @nothingam yes. But I didn't know if the code to perform that was right. If you have correct code for that, then feel free to post as a comment or answer

Comment: I would use OpenSSL to convert them to PKCS12 to PEM and then to DER files.
`openssl pkcs12 -in pack.pfx -out key.pem -nodes -nocerts` and `openssl pkcs12 -in pack.pfx -out cert.pem -nokeys`.
For converting to DER, you can use: `openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out cert.der` and `openssl rsa -inform PEM -in key.pem -outform DER -out key.der`. (but a PEM file is just a Base64'd DER)

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I am writing this from the top of my mind, since I don't personally own a Mac and cannot verify it anymore.

We had this exact problem about a year or two ago at my last job.
It all boils down to Apple dropping support for OpenSSL.

Because of that, Qt switched from OpenSSL backend to Secure Transport backend on Mac with Qt5.6. Now the Secure Transport implementation is lacking some features. For example we were not able to load private key pem-files. I think switching from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1 helped, which can both be stored in `.pem` files and look almost identical, so that took a while to figure out.

We also noticed that a successfully loaded private key will be stored inside the Mac's key store and could be viewed and exported from there by the user, which we also did not want.

We finally went with re-compiling the QtNetwork module to use OpenSSL instead of Secure Transport. You will need to provide OpenSSL for that, since OSX does not include the headers anymore. A homebrew installation was sufficient I think. Other than that the compilation was surprisingly painless and fast, since you just have to compile one small module, not the whole Qt.

The easiest way to do this is:

1. download the source distribution of the Qt version you are running
2. `./configure` it to use OpenSSL (the `-openssl` switch I believe)
3. `cd`into the `network` folder
4. `make`
5. copy the generated `QtNetwork.framework` inside your Qt-Installation and replace the existing one.

With that everything worked as expected.